# I Need a macro who ask from me from the below many different macro which one you need to run

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in a single macro, and i need only one of then to be run as per my choice. I need a main macro who ask from me which code you need to run.

```
Sub Main_Macro
#I don't know how to do this this.
End Sub



Sub Important_Sheet_For_Home()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Home\Template Home.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Cloth()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Cloth\Template Cloth.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Toy()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Toy\Template Toy.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Office()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Office\Template Office.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub


Sub Important_Sheet_For_Beauty()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Beauty\Template For Beauty.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub


Sub Important_Sheet_For_Sport()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Sports\Template Sports.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub

Sub Important_Sheet_For_Home()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Home\Template Home.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Cloth()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Cloth\Template Cloth.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Toy()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Toy\Template Toy.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
Sub Important_Sheet_For_Office()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Office\Template Office.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub


Sub Important_Sheet_For_Beauty()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Beauty\Template For Beauty.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub


Sub Important_Sheet_For_Sport()

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Sports\Template Sports.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template Sports.xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one sub with a parameter:

```
Sub Main_Macro()
    Dim arrThings, thing

    arrThings = Array("Home", "Cloth", "Toy", "Office") 'etc etc

    thing = Application.InputBox("What thing?")

    'is the entered value in arrThings?
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(thing, arrThings, 0)) Then
        'yes - call the sub
        Important_Sheet_For_Something thing
    Else
        MsgBox "Don't recognize this thing '" & thing & "'"
    End If

End Sub

Sub Important_Sheet_For_Something(theThing)

    FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\" & theThing & "\Template " & theThing & ".xlsx", _
             "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Template " & theThing & ".xlsx"

    Dim myfile As Variant
    If MsgBox("Do You Need Translated File", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        FileCopy "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\OneDrive\ICAG\Public\Macro\Translated File\Translated File Template.xlsx", _
            "C:\Users\aarshad.ext\Desktop\New folder\Magic Happens here\Translated File Template.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
```

If you want to stay with your original subs, then you can use Select Case:

```
thing = Application.InputBox("What thing?")

Select Case thing
    Case "Home": Important_Sheet_For_Home
    Case "Cloth": Important_Sheet_For_Cloth
    'other cases
    Case Else: Msgbox "Sorry - no sub for '" & thing & "'" 'default case if no match
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks A lot Sir this is a great help :)

Comment: Hi the above case solution is great. But is it possible that macro ask answer as per drop down style??

Comment: You would need to use a userform for that.  There's no built-in input for that.